# Google play test purchase not working anymore

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, beta-testing

I've got an app long time live on Google Play.

My app has two live versions:

3.18 - production

3.19 - beta

I've waited a day after uploading beta apk to make sure it's ready to go. Then, on my test device, I used opt-link for testers to "Become a tester", which went smoothly. Strangely after installing it from Google Play I checked the version and it's 3.18 so production, not beta. But several minutes later I received an update to 3.19 (so it's beta). App works, I can see price of in-app product, but when I want to buy it it looks like it's a real purchase, because there's not "testing purchase" information anymore.

And I don't want to pay for my own products.

Tested on 2 different test devices, with 2 different accounts and 2 different credit cards.

Is there something new I have to add to my code? I've read that recently google changed something with in-app purchase testing, but as far as I know it's just that you can't see test purchases in merchant account.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.
Seems like I was missing "Gmail accounts with testing access" in **Google Play Console -> Settings -> Account Details**. Strangely I had set it before, but it disappeared.